# how can iOS app set the Core Bluetooth advertisement rate?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-bluetooth

My iOS app running iPad is advertising too often, and subsequently seems to be spamming my embedded Bluetooth LE device, which is reading data out of ad from iPad.

How can I slow down iPad rate of advertising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advertisement rate is not settable in Core Bluetooth. There is no public API that enables you to do it.

While your application is in the foreground, the advertisement will be fast, and in the background it will be limited, most importantly rate throttled down, advertised services removed and local name not used.