# Increase CoreBluetooth advertising frequency

Tags: macos, core-bluetooth

I'm using `CBPeripheralManager` and `- (void)startAdvertising:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData` to advertise as a peripheral on a Mac Mini running OS X Mavericks.

I need to increase the advertisement frequency from the default of I think 1 or 2 Hz to 10Hz.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `setDesiredConnectionLatency:forCentral:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the advertisement frequency. It is completely under the control of CoreBluetooth. See [how can iOS app set the Core Bluetooth advertisement rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412903/how-can-ios-app-set-the-core-bluetooth-advertisement-rate/21431335#21431335)

I've got to check the advertisement rate but on iOS I think it's sent at around 20ms delay which results 50/sec or so. Background advertisement is a different story, read about it.

Comment: I'm not using iOS – as I said in my question I'm using Mavericks. I'm wondering if there's a better way than to use bluez via a Linux VM running on Mavericks.

Comment: There is no difference in the core bluetooth APIs between iOS and OSx and no API is available to change the advertisement rate. I haven't tried if a Linux VM could access the BLE functions of the host but that may work.